# Differentiability Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following true/false claim:

There exists a function $f(x,y)$  which is differentiable function at $(x_0,y_0) $ and its directional derivatives at each direction $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta )$  for $0\leq \theta <2\pi $ equal $\cos^2 \theta + 2\sin \theta $ .

I am almost sure this claim is false but can't understand exactly why . 
I guess that this is because if such a question was true, the gradient should have been dependent on the angle, which isn't possible.

Can someone help me understand how to formalize this argument?

Thanks !

Comment: It's not necessarily false. This would be found by taking the gradient first, and then plugging in $(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$ for x and y, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wlog $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$. The derivative in direction $v$ is $\nabla f|_{(0,0)}\cdot v$. Now consider
$$v=(1,0)^t = (\cos(0),\sin(0))^t$$
Then by assumption
$$\nabla f|_{(0,0)}\cdot v = 1$$
and
$$\nabla f|_{(0,0)}\cdot (-v) = \nabla f|_{(0,0)}\cdot (\cos(\pi),\sin(\pi)) = 1\neq -\nabla f|_{(0,0)}\cdot v$$
This is a contradiction.